# How to convert text to multiple xml in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml" description="Select Sheets">
                <format>
                    <Response>$1</Response>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('name')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>   
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var csv = mc.getPayloadXML();   
  var lines = (csv + "").split("\n");
    for (var l = 1; l <= lines.length; l++) {
      cells = (lines[l] + "").split(";");
  }
]]></script>
```

I am trying to get the data from excel through esb option, and i am getting the output also but not properly getting. Please guide me to do. Retrieving the data From multiple excel sheets or multiple excel files are working from that retrieved data i formed csv. From the csv i need to form multiple xml then need to insert into db. How to form csv to multiple xml?

suppose some sheets containing 3 columns,4 columns or 5 columns. Depends on that need to form child node of xml.

Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data-mapper mediator to construct a xml payload using the csv file. Please refer the [examples](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Data+Mapper+Mediator#DataMapperMediator-Examples) related to CSV and XML transformations.

For example, you can create a xml payload depending on the number of columns in  csv sheet.

```html
<rows>
  <row>
    <col1>value1</col1>
    <col2>value2</col2>
    <col3>value3</col3>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col1>value4</col1>
    <col2>value5</col2>
    <col3>value6</col3>
  </row>
</rows>
```

Once you have created the xml payload, you can use [Iterate](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Iterate+Mediator) mediator or [ForEach](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/ForEach+Mediator) mediator to iterate through each sub xml element (i.e. elements start with 'row' tag) for a given xpath (eg: xpath="//row"), and execute db queries for each sub element.

If you are using a data service to execute insert queries, you can use the Iterate mediator, which calls the data service for each xml sub element. Else, you can use ForEach mediator along with [DBReport](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/DB+Report+Mediator) mediator to execute insert queries for each xml sub element.

Comment: please let me know, how to segregate those data into multiple tables 1st row data into one table 2nd row data into one table?

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><sample>
  <employee>
    <value><sheet name="Sheet1">FirstName</value>
    <value>LastName</value>
    <value>DOB</value>
    <value>Emp Id</value>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <value>Sumathi</value>
    <value>Marimuthu</value>
    <value>240391.0</value>
    <value>11011.0</value>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <value>Sumathi</value>
    <value>Muthuraman</value>
    <value>250514.0</value>
    <value>13473.0&lt;/sheet></value>
  </employee>

Comment: <employee>
    <value><sheet name="Sheet2">FirstName</value>
    <value>LastName</value>
    <value>DOB</value>
    <value>EmpId</value>
    <value>Email</value>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <value>Sumathi</value>
    <value>Marimuthu</value>
    <value>24391.0</value>
    <value>11011.0</value>
    <value>sumathi.mar24@gmail.com</value>
  </employee>   
</sample></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Above 2 are my output i need to insert those data into multiple tables. Please guide me how to do..